# Can we use "guard" instead of let <var> = try? <action> in swift?

Tags: swift

What is the difference between:

```
guard let json_data = Data(contentsOf: path) else {return nil}
```

and

```
let json_data = try? Data(contentsOf: path)
```

I dont want to use optional while loading the data into the variable. I want other ways to try it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you forgive the completely unrelated observation, I would advise `jsonData` in lieu of `json_data`, following the camel-case convention we use in Swift for variable and method names.

Answer (score 5):

The options are:

1. Your first example, unwrapping it with `guard`, is missing a `try?`:

   ```swift
   func foo() -> Bar? {
       guard let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: path) else { return nil }

       // if you get here, `jsonData` is not `Optional`

       …
   }
   ```

   This will safely unwrap your optional and let you do whatever you want if the unwrapping failed. (In your example, you are returning `nil`.)
2. Your second example, yields an optional, which you presumably need to unwrap with an `if` statement.

   ```swift
   func foo() -> Bar? {
       let jsonData = try? Data(contentsOf: path)

       // jsonData is `Optional` in this example

       if let jsonData {
           …
       } else {
           return nil
       }
   }
   ```

   We would generally favor the first option over this, where the “early exit” of the `guard` makes it a little easier to read the code, but there are cases where you might use this pattern.
3. An option that hasn’t been considered is to actually throw the error (using `try` instead of `try?`):

   ```swift
   func foo() throws -> Bar {
       let jsonData = try Data(contentsOf: path)

       // `jsonData` is not `Optional`

       …
   }
   ```

   Now, this only passes the buck of handling the error to the caller (i.e., a `do`-`catch` block). But it does have a few virtues over the prior two examples, namely that (a) the useful information of the error object is not just discarded, thereby making it easier to diagnose problems during the development process; and (b) you don’t have to return an optional.
4. Yet another option (to be used only if you know that this will *always* succeed, e.g., you are reading a well-known file from your bundle that you know must always succeed) is `try!`, a “force-try”:

   ```swift
   func foo() -> Bar {
       let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: path)

       // `jsonData` is not `Optional`

       …
   }
   ```

   Now, this will crash if the `Data(contentsOf:)` can ever fail, so only use this in scenarios where you know that this is impossible.

Personally, I would generally favor option 3 (where I capture what went wrong) in cases where the `Data(contentsOf:)` might ever plausibly fail at runtime, and I might consider option 4 (where it crashes with a meaningful error message) when I know it is impossible for it to *ever* fail at runtime. That having been said, more than once I found myself using option 4 and I later regretted not using option 3, simply because there was some weird edge-case that I neglected to consider.

In short, nowadays I tend to defensively `catch` errors, log the full error in the console and show a nice localized message in the UI (i.e., option 3). I almost never use `try?`, because if something can fail, it’s rarely a good idea to discard the useful diagnostic information.

Answer (score -1):

It will be better to be optional once  you are loading the data to avoid application crash in and problems in case there was no data there. This is consider as a safe feature.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).